# How to ping message author and user in Discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i recently started with Discord.js and i am currently making a hug command. the command itself is working fine, but the problem i am facing is that i want the bot to ping the message author and the user that gets hugged. if i type in the command "a!hug @user" this is what i get: "<@1389615656215> hugged username", but i want it to show up like this: "@user hugged @user".

below is my code

```
const personHugged = message.mentions.users.first();

if(personHugged){
  let hugEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author} hugged ${personHugged.username} :heart:`)
      .setImage(images[Math. floor(Math. random()*images. length)])
      .setTimestamp()
  message.channel.send(hugEmbed);
}
else{
  message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author} that user is not in this server!`);
}
```

I really hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have mentions in embed titles. The only place you can add them is a field (using [`addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField), or [`addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields)) or the description (using [`setDescription`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription))

```js
let hugEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Woo, that's a hug :heart:`)
  .setDescription(`${message.author} hugged ${personHugged} :heart:`)
  .setImage(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)])
  .setTimestamp();
message.channel.send(hugEmbed);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! this was exactly what i needed and its working now!