# Discord.js Slash command mention user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ive been trying to figure out how to get my hug command to mention both the sender and the recipient of the command. As well as when you start the command it'll ask for the sender to select someone to mention before the command is sent off (or is that built in? I don't know yet)

I have read over the docs of the user class and as well as read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487894/discord-js-hug-command-how-to-ping-message-author-and-user-that-gets-hugged) post here but have come to the conclusion that both aren't using slash commands though which is what ive been taught of how to do, not using embeds or text for the commands, just a slash command. If there is any help to this that would be greatly appreciated!
Here's my resulting code so far though

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hug')
        .setDescription('Hug Someone'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        return interaction.reply(`${user} hugs ${user}`)
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the author of the [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction) using the [`Interaction#user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user) property.

To specify a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) to hug you'll have to add a [`SlashCommandUserOption`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandUserOption).

You can then get the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) by using [`CommandInteractionOptionResolver#getUser`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getUser)

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hug')
        .setDescription('Hug Someone')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('The user you want to hug')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        return interaction.reply(`${interaction.user} hugs ${interaction.options.getUser('user')}`)
    },
};
```