# member cannot be mentioned in the embed discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making a join and leave log system that returns a specific embed when someone joins/leaves the server. but when the bot sends the embed in the channel, the member is not mentioned.

My code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{

    const embed7 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({name: `${guildMember.user.username}`, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dyanmic: true})})
    .addField(`<@${guildMember.id}>`, 'Joined the server')
    .addFields(
        {name: "**Member ID**", value: guildMember.id, inline: true},
        {name: "Joined Discord:", value: `<t:${parseInt(guildMember.user.createdTimestamp / 1000, 10)}:R>`, inline: true},
    )
    .setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Join Log | PDM Building'})
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('948686135264178206').send({embeds: [embed7]})
});
client.on('guildMemberRemove', guildMember => {
    const embed8 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({name: guildMember.user.username, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dyanmic: true})})
    .setTitle(`<@${guildMember.user.id}> left the server`)
    .addField(`<@${guildMember.id}>`, 'Left the server')
    .setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Leave Log | PDM Building'})
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('948686135264178206').send({embeds: [embed8]})
  });
```

Notes: **No one can see the channel that I am sending this embed to, just me and the bot**

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ping message author and user in Discord.js embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487894/how-to-ping-message-author-and-user-in-discord-js-embed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mention a user in an embed **title** or field **header**,  you can't a mention user in the embed footer either.

You can do that in the embed description and field values only.