# How do I mention a user with the blue highlight in Discord Embed?

Tags: discord.js

I'm well aware pinging someone with mentions in an embed is impossible, but I still want the blue highlight.

Example:

An image that shows a random bot that is able to mention with blue highlights in an embed that doesn't ping but only mention.

[image]

Here's mine, an image that shows my bot that mentions without a blue highlight in an embed.

[image]

Here's What I Did:

```
 if(command === 'hug2') {

        let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        if(!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to mention a user in order to hug them!!');

        const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag} Just Gave <@${targetMember.user.id}> a Hug!`)
        .setColor('0x0099FF')
        .setImage('http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma7l17EWnk1rq65rlo1_500.gif')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: 'Made With Horikita Bot!', iconURL: 'https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2021/01/26/23/55/26/87326371_p0_square1200.jpg' });
    
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ping message author and user in Discord.js embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487894/how-to-ping-message-author-and-user-in-discord-js-embed)

Comment: Try `targetMember.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is probably the fact that you're trying to mention a user in the title of the embed. Try setting the description instead.

```js
if(command === 'hug2') {
  let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  if(!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to mention a user in order to hug them!!');
  const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('hug')
    .setDescription(`${message.author.tag} Just Gave <@${targetMember.user.id}> a Hug!`)
    .setColor('0x0099FF')
    .setImage('http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma7l17EWnk1rq65rlo1_500.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Made With Horikita Bot!', iconURL: 'https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2021/01/26/23/55/26/87326371_p0_square1200.jpg' });
    
  message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
```

I'm not sure of any reason for it to be impossible to mention in an embed's title, but at the very least, this *should* work.

Comment: Changing it to the description does indeed work, however the ${message.author.tag} still does not gets highlighted, it needs to be changed to ${message.author.toString().

Comment: Forgot to say thank you to you!